# Ionic badge appear difference from android and ios

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, badge

The badge's appearance on android seems to be overlay with something while in ios its works fine.
Badge on IOS is brighter than android...any clue on this?
I've posted here for the image n code : 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4937